# Detect if a .NET Thread is Running

Tags: .net, multithreading, c++-cli, clr

I'm working with C++/CLI and I created 2 Threads.

```
loadedThreads = gcnew array<Thread^>(2);
len = 2;

Thread^ th1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&Ping)); loadedThreads[0] = th1;
Thread^ th2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(&Ping)); loadedThreads[1] = th2;

th1->Start();
th2->Start();

threadsCreated = true;
```

both threads are checking if each other are alive:

```
void Ping()
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(!threadsCreated) { Thread::Sleep(25); continue; }

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            Thread^ t = loadedThreads[i];

            if(!t->IsAlive())
            {
                _log("some thread is not running");
            }
        }

        Thread::Sleep(25);
    }
}
```

But if I terminate the thread with ProcessHacker, the thread will no longer run but it will still be marked as alive (IsAlive = true, ThreadState = Running)

Is it a bug? Is it a exploit Process Hacker uses?

Comment: CLR threads aren't just thin wrappers over OS threads. I won't write a full answer since I'm typing this on a tablet, but I can point you at [this function](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/vm/comsynchronizable.cpp#L117) which is indirectly  called when you read the `IsAlive` property. It maintains a state variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.NET/CLR threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are managed threads; managed within the context of the application that is. Managed threads do more than start a thread in the OS, they keep state of the thread object for a more developer friendly way of managing threads.

When you start a thread, the OS has to manage this thread (regardless if it came from .NET, Java or C) and an external program (like Process Hacker) can see these threads much like an external program can see the processes running on the system. Process Hacker and programs like it that can terminate threads usually just grab the OS thread ID and call the WinAPI function [`TerminateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which essentially kills the active thread without a chance for any other user code to execute on it.

For managed threads this means that when you call the [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, the `Thread` class will keep state of the internal thread it created (e.g. the thread's ID, set thread state to 'running', call user function, etc.) and when the thread function ends, the `Thread` class then cleans up and sets the appropriate flags (e.g. thread state set to 'stopped' for normal termination or 'aborted' if [`Abort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was called). To this, if you kill the thread from an external program (like Process Hacker), the `Thread` class code doesn't have a chance to preform the clean up code and thus reset the flags to their valid values, that is, the `Thread` class still thinks the thread it has is valid. It should be noted that acting on the thread object after you've killed it via Process Hacker will more than likely result in a crash or undefined behaviour.

It should also be noted that there's not much of a way to detect if the thread has been forcibly killed outside of your code. You could join on the thread or implement a sort of heartbeat in the thread code, but this still isn't guaranteed (especially if you implement any sort of sync locks). If the thread is killed the most you might know is that thread has ended by some means, and as you've noted, it could result in invalid states.

So, to answer directly:

> Is it a bug?

No, this is expected behaviour given the context.

> Is it a exploit Process Hacker uses?

No, per my answer above, it more than likely uses the `TerminateThread` function, which does require admin privileges though.

Hope that can help.

Comment: "It should also be noted that there's not much of a way to detect if the thread has been forcibly killed outside of your code" - the thread handle is wait-able (signaled when the thread terminates) you should be able to register a callback with the thread pool to be called when the thread handle is signaled. I believe the CLR reserves the right to shuffle managed threads between native threads (in which case this will become unreliable) but doesn't currently do so.

Comment: @BrianReichle, true, one could join on the thread and when the thread was killed you could assume the thread has ended, but I was more meaning that if you forcibly killed the thread, the most you would know is the thread ended and not necessarily if it was killed or just ended since the state of the thread (and any associated code) might be in an invalid state.